# How to improve eslint-plugin-angular on-watch error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eslint

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, state) {
            ...
        })
```

result -> es lint error  The "$on" call should be assigned to a variable, in order to be destroyed during the $destroy event

but if i correct it like in the [documentation](https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular/blob/master/docs/on-watch.md)

```
var unregister = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, state) {
            ...
        })
```

i get "unregister is defined but never used" error

What is the best way to correct this issue?

Comment: The rule appears to check that the variable is [used as an argument](https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular/blob/1.4.1/rules/on-watch.js#L66-L73) in `$destroy` call. Are you doing that? Or are you just assigning to an otherwise ignored variable?

Comment: no, not doing that, the variable won't be cleaned up automatically?

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with AngularJS, so I'm no authority on this stuff, but I think the point of the rule is that watches on the `$rootScope` won't be cleaned up automatically and that `$destroy` needs to be called (and passed the variable).

Comment: thx, this is the point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unregister` variable that is returned by `$rootScope.$on` is a function that needs to be called to unregister the watch. A common use case is to call it when the current scope is destroyed:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', unregister);
```